# pyparsing definition of a word as contiguous block of chars

Tags: pyparsing

I'm trying to extract an id and data from the following sample line. 
I defined the id as something that would have alphanums and a few other chars but excluding comma. I expected pyparsing not to pick up the digit 1 of the data as part of the id because the data is contiguous block which includes comma and comma is excluded from the id. Should pyparsing not reject the data part in its entirety as an id because that contiguous block of data contains other chars not defined in the id part? My expectation was that the rules are applied to words as a whole and not pieces of words

```
joinTokensViaSpace = lambda tokens: " ".join(" ".join(t.split()) for t in tokens)
parser= OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-/.'))('id').setParseAction(joinTokensViaSpace) + Word(nums+',.()')('data') 
parser.parseString('                    XXX Y/123          1,234.567890')
```

output i get

> (['XXX Y/1231', ',234.567890'], {'data': [(',234.567890', 1)], 'id': [('XXX Y/1231', 0)]})

output i expect
(['XXX Y/123', '1,234.567890'], {'data': [('1,234.567890', 1)], 'id': [('XXX Y/123', 0)]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `Word` usually parses on whitespace, but it is not guaranteed as you have found. I tried changing your parser a bit to add `Word`'s optional `asKeyword=True` argument, and also using `Regex` with surrounding `\b` markers, but in both cases, the ',' in `1,234.567890` satisfied the normal word-break behavior.

The simplest solution is to insert a negative lookahead inside your `OneOrMore`, before matching on `Word(alphanums+'-/.')`:

```
number = Word(nums+',.()')
parser= OneOrMore(~number + Word(alphanums+'-/.'))('id')\
            .setParseAction(joinTokensViaSpace) + number('data')
```

This way, before starting another `Word`, the parser first checks to see if it is at a potential `number`, and only proceeds if it is not. With this change, the parsed output will be as you expect. (Perhaps I should add a `stopOn` argument to `OneOrMore` and `ZeroOrMore`, like `OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-/.'), stopOn=number)` - this is really a very common pitfall for pyparsing developers.)

I also see that you are using results names - that is a good habit to get into. Since you have them, I suggest you use `dump()` as the best tool for examining the `ParseResults` structure returned by `parseString`.

```
result = parser.parseString('                    XXX Y/123          1,234.567890')
print result.dump()
```

prints

```
['XXX Y/123', '1,234.567890']
- data: 1,234.567890
- id: XXX Y/123
```

Comment: The `stopOn` keyword argument will be included in the next release of pyparsing, version 2.1.0.